# find command of nobody runs on every fresh boot in the morning - debian stretch

Tags: find, background-process, webserver, daemon

Folks,

`find` executed by nobody runs automatically on every fresh boot (in the morning when I boot the system). I guess it is to do with `updatedb`. How can I confirm my assumption and stop this from executing automatically. My `ps aux | grep find` output is as follows:

```
~~> ps aux | grep find
root      4492  0.0  0.0   4288   748 ?        SN   08:10   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/updatedb.findutils
root      4500  0.0  0.0   4288   108 ?        SN   08:10   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/updatedb.findutils
root      4526  0.0  0.0  55444  2988 ?        SN   08:10   0:00 su nobody -s /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/find / -ignore_readdir_race      \( -fstype NFS -o -fstype nfs -o -fstype nfs4 -o -fstype afs -o -fstype binfmt_misc -o -fstype proc -o -fstype smbfs -o -fstype autofs -o -fstype iso9660 -o -fstype ncpfs -o -fstype coda -o -fstype devpts -o -fstype ftpfs -o -fstype devfs -o -fstype mfs -o -fstype shfs -o -fstype sysfs -o -fstype cifs -o -fstype lustre_lite -o -fstype tmpfs -o -fstype usbfs -o -fstype udf -o -fstype ocfs2 -o      -type d -regex '\(^/tmp$\)\|\(^/usr/tmp$\)\|\(^/var/tmp$\)\|\(^/afs$\)\|\(^/amd$\)\|\(^/alex$\)\|\(^/var/spool$\)\|\(^/sfs$\)\|\(^/media$\)\|\(^/var/lib/schroot/mount$\)' \) -prune -o -print0
nobody    4538  0.0  0.0   4288   748 ?        SNs  08:10   0:00 sh -c /usr/bin/find / -ignore_readdir_race      \( -fstype NFS -o -fstype nfs -o -fstype nfs4 -o -fstype afs -o -fstype binfmt_misc -o -fstype proc -o -fstype smbfs -o -fstype autofs -o -fstype iso9660 -o -fstype ncpfs -o -fstype coda -o -fstype devpts -o -fstype ftpfs -o -fstype devfs -o -fstype mfs -o -fstype shfs -o -fstype sysfs -o -fstype cifs -o -fstype lustre_lite -o -fstype tmpfs -o -fstype usbfs -o -fstype udf -o -fstype ocfs2 -o      -type d -regex '\(^/tmp$\)\|\(^/usr/tmp$\)\|\(^/var/tmp$\)\|\(^/afs$\)\|\(^/amd$\)\|\(^/alex$\)\|\(^/var/spool$\)\|\(^/sfs$\)\|\(^/media$\)\|\(^/var/lib/schroot/mount$\)' \) -prune -o -print0
nobody    4539  7.9  0.0  16844  2752 ?        DN   08:10   0:06 /usr/bin/find / -ignore_readdir_race ( -fstype NFS -o -fstype nfs -o -fstype nfs4 -o -fstype afs -o -fstype binfmt_misc -o -fstype proc -o -fstype smbfs -o -fstype autofs -o -fstype iso9660 -o -fstype ncpfs -o -fstype coda -o -fstype devpts -o -fstype ftpfs -o -fstype devfs -o -fstype mfs -o -fstype shfs -o -fstype sysfs -o -fstype cifs -o -fstype lustre_lite -o -fstype tmpfs -o -fstype usbfs -o -fstype udf -o -fstype ocfs2 -o -type d -regex \(^/tmp$\)\|\(^/usr/tmp$\)\|\(^/var/tmp$\)\|\(^/afs$\)\|\(^/amd$\)\|\(^/alex$\)\|\(^/var/spool$\)\|\(^/sfs$\)\|\(^/media$\)\|\(^/var/lib/schroot/mount$\) ) -prune -o -print0
cathyserver  5223  0.0  0.0  13380   940 pts/1    S+   08:12   0:00 grep find
```

First impression is that it some daemon is scouting the `/var /tmp /var/spool /alex /amd /afs /var/tmp` for something. How can I find which process/daemon executes this? Is this any webserver? By the way I do not have any `/alex /amd` directories in my system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `find` is indeed part of `updatedb`, which runs daily, triggered by the `cron` daemon.

You can verify by comparing the `find` parameters from your process list against the configuration in `/etc/updatedb.conf`.

On Debian Stretch you can switch the `locate` and its corresponding `updatedb` command between the alternatives `mlocate` and `locate.findutils`:

```
sudo apt install mlocate locate
sudo update-alternatives --config locate
```

### mlocate

`cron` daemon uses `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate`.

To disable the daily run you can either uninstall the package `mlocate` or disable its cron job by removing execution right:

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/cron.daily/mlocate
```

To re-enable it:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/mlocate
```

### locate.findutils

`cron` daemon uses `/etc/cron.daily/locate`.

To disable the daily run you can either uninstall the package `locate` or disable its cron job by removing execution right:

```
sudo chmod -x /etc/cron.daily/locate
```

To re-enable it:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/locate
```

*Source for disable/enable lines: https://askubuntu.com/questions/268130/can-i-disable-updatedb-mlocate*

Comment: Thanks @Marvin. It is indeed run by the `updatedb`. However, a change in your technical elaboration: Instead of `mlocate` it is `locate` in my system ( I do not know is that to do with debian stretch). The command that triggers the `find` operation is `updatedb.findutils`. One thing which I am yet to understand is the `prunepaths`. In my output, I have direcotories `/alex /amd ...`. In my configuration I couldn't find any `/alex` rather only `/amd`. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry @RussellB, though I am using Debian Stretch, I was not aware of the alternative package `locate`. I have now adjusted my answer to reflect both `locate` packages. Also I tried to find information about the `/alex` path, but could not. `PRUNEPATHS` on my system is configured to `"/tmp /var/spool /media /var/lib/os-prober /var/lib/ceph"`, no `/alex` nor `/amd`. Does a `sudo grep -r "/alex" /etc` give you any hit?

Comment: Oh my! I found `/alex`! It's in the `/etc/cron.daily/locate:PRUNEPATHS` variable. Thanks Marvin for updating the answer.